# How to use Perl to copy files from ssh server?

Tags: perl, ssh

My requirement is find for specific files (filename.tup) on remote machine and based on that file copy other files from sub-directories (where the filename.tup file was found).
here is my trial script.

```
use File::Basename ;

@tuppaths=`ssh $host "/usr/bin/find /cygdrive/d/jobs/Results/$Target/$build/ -type f -name *.tup -print"`;
##above cmd will print the file name along with directory path e.g. /jobs/results/xxxxx/xxxxx/20150208_105308_j260_b150208/filename.tup

foreach my $tups (@tuppaths) { 
    my $copytups = $tups; ## this shows all the *.tup with fullpath
}
```

From here how to go to each directories where each filename.tup is located and search for .txt and .xml files (in sub-dirs of each filename.tup) and copy them to my local machine by creating new directories for each filename.tup.

for copying files planning to use rsync or scp (i tried manually copying through scp and it works).
Please guide me how could i do this using perl scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse paths with something like this http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html
Than you do ssh again, doing something like 'ls $dirname/*.txt' and parse elements in another cycle using mkdir function to create local dirs and scp to fetch files.

Comment: thank you mickvav... i made some progress with your suggestion. were i could able to do ssh again for concat.txt files and locate them.

Answer (score 0):

Hello sorry for late replay, i was out of town :)
here is the code i tried and it works fine.
@serenesat, i didn't try with use::scp and i feel system execution looks okay for now.

```
use File::Basename;
use Getopt::Long;

my $Target = undef;
my $build = undef;
my $host1 = undef;
my $USER = tester;

GetOptions (
            't|target=s'        => \$Target,
            'b|build=s'     => \$build,
            'h|host1=s' => \$host1,

        );
my $host = "$USER" . "@" . "$host1";
my $Test_dir = "Test_reports_" . "$build";
mkdir $Test_dir;
my $Results = "/cygdrive/C/Results/$Test_dir";



 @tuppaths = `ssh $host "/usr/bin/find /cygdrive/d/jobs/Results/$Target/$build/ -type f -name *.tup -print"`;

            print "TUPPATHS\n@tuppaths\n";
            foreach my $dirpath(@tuppaths) {
            my ($tup,$dir) = fileparse($dirpath);
                my @tupname = split('.tup', $tup);
                print "tupnames==>@tupname<===\n";

            $testdirname = "$Results/$tupname[0]";

            mkdir $testdirname;
            print "creating directory for $tupname[0]\n";

            #Get the concat text reports
            #print "ssh $host /usr/bin/find $dir -type f -name *_concat.txt -print\n";
            @txt_reports = `ssh $host " /usr/bin/find $dir -type f -name *_concat.txt -print"`;


                foreach my $reportpath (@txt_reports) {

                        my ($concat,$dirs) = fileparse($reportpath);

                        print "copying $concat to $tupname[0] \n";
                        system ("scp","$host:$dirs$concat"," ","$testdirname"); # scp command to copy concat.txt files to related test directories
            #Get the xml concat reports     
            @xml_reports = `ssh $host " /usr/bin/find $dir -type f -name *_concat.xml -print"`;

                foreach my $xml_reportpath (@xml_reports) {

                        my ($xml,$dirs) = fileparse($xml_reportpath);

                        print "copying $concat to $tupname[0] \n";
                        system ("scp","$host:$dirs$xml"," ","$testdirname"); # scp command to copy concat.xml files to related test directories

            #Get fail reports
            @afrs = `ssh $host " /usr/bin/find $dir -type d -name atomic_fail_reports -print"`;             

                        foreach my $pathtoafrs (@afrs) {

                        my ($afr, $afrdir) = fileparse ($pathtoafrs);
                        #print "afr =>$afr\n";
                        #print "afrdir =>$afrdir\n";
                        print "coyping $tupname[0] AFRs to $tupname[0] directory \n";
                        system ("scp","-r","$host:$afrdir$afr"," ","$testdirname")
                        }

                }


                }

            }
    print "Sucessfully Finished copying reports for $build\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

use a `CPAN` module like `Net::SCP` or others to securely copy files between servers.

```
use Net::SCP;

$scp = Net::SCP->new( { 
    "host"=>$hostname, 
    "user"=>$username 
} );

$scp->scp($source, $destination);
```

Have a look here https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SCP

Comment: thank you serenesat, can i use without NET::SCP , actually i'm trying to use scp as a system command and execute it .e.g `scp $host:$dirs $concat $testdirname`;  however it is not working and the same command  works if i execute on shell manually.

Comment: What is not working? What are the errors getting you? can you show us your full command what you are executing manually?

Comment: the scp command fails if i use it in perl,
 my $cmd = "scp -v $host\:$pathtofile  $destination";
 `$cmd`;   i get following error for above command,                                                                                    usage: scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
           [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2sh: line 1: /cygdrive/C/Data/reports/tests/: is a directory               
if i try same command manually it works fine:
scp username@hostname:/cygdrive/c/reports/concat.txt  /cydrive/c/Data/reports/test
I'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

Comment: I guess it's problem with space b/w $pathofile and $destination (some how the space is not taking) 
it works fine if i use it as a system command 
"system ("scp","$host:$dpathtofile"," ","$destination");"
i will also try to use Net::SCP as you suggested... thank you

Comment: @praneeth : If still you have some problem just show us your full perl code. `system` is a way of executing unix\linux command through the perl script.